Detecting Bluetooth peripheral shutdown from Android App
I have a Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral device which I am connecting to from an Android app which I have developed. I can use onConnectionStateChange to detect when the devices move out of range and notify the user accordingly. However, if I simply power off the peripheral, I can't figure out if it is possible to detect the disconnection directly. What I do instead is to use onCharacteristicWrite to catch the next attempt by the app to write a characteristic (this is all the app does) which results in a GATT failure due to the disconnection.
I understand that it is possible to broadcast a heartbeat from the peripheral, but an iOS developer that I am working alongside is able to detect the disconnection directly through the iOS API, so I was wondering if I was missing something in the Android API, which is new to me.

Don't you get a BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED on onConnectionStateChange when you turn of the peripheral? See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666976/7473793

That is what I expected to get, but I do not get anything, Thanks for the link; I missed that one and will have a look now.

Bluetooth SIG has specified the Link Loss Service for precisely this purpose. This can be implemented accordingly on both Android and iOS.

My question is not about the spec, but the current implementation of the spec in Android.

Thanks @MichaelKotzjan for pointing me in the direction of the actual API behaviour in Android. On the back of this - yes, when I abruptly power down the device, I do indeed see the  BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED on onConnectionStateChange.
Apologies - previously, when I said I was powering off the device, I was actually only killing the peripheral service on the device rather than actually powering the device off. My peripheral code was not catching ctrl-c interruptions and closing the connection explicitly.

Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted once the 48 hour are over to help others find a solution quicker :) https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/
